DateTime filtering based on a date range and a time range
I need to filter data for more than two days and at the same time, I need to filter different time periods. In this scenario, my query does not work because the start time is larger than the end time.
For example, I want to filter the data from 23:00 to 2:00 and definitely because 23 is greater than 2, no data is returned.
DECLARE @fromdate date = '2024-09-13',
        @todate date = '2024-09-14',
        @fromtime time = '20:00:00',
        @totime time = '02:00:00'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT    
        CreateDate
    FROM  
        (VALUES ('2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343'),
                ('2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343')) x (CreateDate)
)
SELECT 
    CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) 
FROM 
    cte AS r
WHERE  
    CAST(r.CreateDate AS date) >= @fromdate 
    AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS date) <= @todate 
    AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) >= @fromtime 
    AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) <= @totime 

I need data between 2024-09-13 20:00:00 and 2024-09-14 2:00:00 
Result should be:



Result




2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837


2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343



but my query returns nothing.
One point: I need to pass date and time separately
If I change the where clause like this:
WHERE CAST(r.CreateDate AS datetime2) 
  BETWEEN 
     CAST('2024-09-13 20:00:00' AS datetime2)
     AND
     CAST('2024-09-14 2:00:00' AS datetime2)

It still doesn't work its returns



Result




2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343



but correct result is:



Result




2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837


2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343



For clarity I need this range of data


"I need to pass date and time separately" Why are you separating your date and time portions? Why do you "need" to? That's the problem here. What time (of day) is after 20:00 but before 02:00? Hint; there is none, and so your results will always be none too.

Just to check: are you wanting to return data from 13th and 14th, but only from 00:00 to 02:00 and from 20:00 to 24:00 ? Or some other filtering?

Even if you pass date and time separately you can join them back in the query: between (FromDate + FromDateTime) and (ToDate + ToDateTime)

@ThomA I have updated my question, please check it again

@Charlieface If it is possible, send it as a answer , I would appreciate it

@topsail I have updated my question, please check it again

Works fine for me: db<>fiddle What happens if you use an unambiguous datetime literal? (yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss or yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss)

@ThomA its not returned my needed data for example '00:16:34' dose not exist result please check result again

@DaleK its just a sample data

Why would that return, @Jack, it's on the 13th not the 14th... So do you want any values on or after 20:00, or before or on 02:00 exclusive of date? If so, why the date filtering?

So is the logic I described above correct, yes or no?

You say you "need data between 2024-09-13 20:00:00 and 2024-09-14 2:00:00" but your expected result contains 2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570 which is before 2024-09-13 20:00:00.

"Correct result" is not correct, 2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570 is like 20 hrs before 2024-09-13 20:00:00

maybe I didn't convey my meaning correctly, I added a picture for your better understanding

@jack Your picture is not entirely clear. Do you want just six hours in total? As if someone had a six hour shift starting at 2000 and ending at 0200?

@Schwern yes i need  just six hours in total

@jack If you want six hours in total, can you explain why your "correct result" spans from 2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570 to 2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343? That's almost 26 hours.

It looks like the logic is a little more involved, as you are expecting that if @fromtime is greater than @totime then it acts as two independent filters.
DECLARE @fromdate date = '2024-09-13',
        @todate date = '2024-09-14',
        @fromtime time = '20:00:00',
        @totime time = '02:00:00';

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT    
        CAST(CreateDate AS datetime2) AS CreateDate
    FROM  
        (VALUES ('2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343'),
                ('2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343')) x (CreateDate)
)
SELECT 
    r.CreateDate
FROM 
    cte AS r
WHERE  
    r.CreateDate >= CAST(@fromdate AS datetime2)
    AND r.CreateDate < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@todate AS datetime2))
    AND
    (
      (
        @fromtime < @totime
        AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) >= @fromtime 
        AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) <= @totime
      ) OR
      (
        @fromtime > @totime
        AND NOT
        (
              CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) >= @fromtime 
          AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) <= @totime
        )
      )
    );

db<>fiddle

its return 2024-09-14 18:21:27 that was not correct

No it doesn't @jack . Check the fiddle.

sorry my bad thats work fine, you are right. It is possible. Please give a detailed explanation about this problem. I would appreciate it. And does this query work for normal dates and times, for example, only for one day? thank you

Separating datetime is the problem here, Where clause will never be satisfied if the date and time are separate.
You could try something like this.
DECLARE @fromdate date = '2024-09-13',
        @todate date = '2024-09-14',
        @fromtime time = '20:00:00',
        @totime time = '02:00:00'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT    
        CreateDate
    FROM  
        (VALUES ('2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343'),
                ('2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570'),
                ('2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320'),
                ('2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434'),
                ('2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837'),
                ('2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006'),
                ('2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343')) x (CreateDate)
)
SELECT 
    CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) 
FROM 
    cte AS r
WHERE  
 CAST(r.CreateDate AS datetime2) >= CONVERT( Datetime,CAST(@fromdate AS DATETIME) + CAST(@fromtime AS DATETIME))
 AND CAST(r.CreateDate AS datetime2) <= CONVERT( Datetime,CAST(@todate AS DATETIME) + CAST(@totime AS DATETIME))


I think, query will return all rows between 20:00 and 2:00 thru midnight for dates 2024-09-13 and 2024-09-14.
In this case, it is logical to set the date and time separately.
For example if @fromtime='20:00' and @totime='02:00' then filter should return rows
from '2024-09-13 20:00:00' to '2024-09-14 02:00:00'
and from '2024-09-14 20:00:00' to '2024-09-14 23:59:59'
If @fromtime is '02:00' and @totime='20:00' filter should return rows
from '2024-09-13 02:00:00' to '2024-09-13 20:00:00'
and from '2024-09-14 02:00:00' to '2024-09-14 20:00:00'.



CreateDate




2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837


2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837


2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343


2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343



SELECT CreateDate
FROM cte as r
WHERE CAST(r.CreateDate AS date) between @fromdate and @todate
 and (
   (@toTime<=@fromtime 
     and (CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) >=@fromtime 
     or CAST(r.CreateDate AS time)<=@totime )
   )
  or((@toTime>=@fromtime 
     and (CAST(r.CreateDate AS time) >=@fromtime 
        and CAST(r.CreateDate AS time)<=@totime )
   )





CreateDate




2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343



fiddle
